# Apache Pig Date time - invalid format error

Tags: casting, apache-pig, jodatime

I have a problem with pig datetime datatype. I am tried to using but format is not working properly. I don't understand what the error is : The code used is below

```
`records = LOAD '/tmp/project/sample.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (CUSTOMER_ID:in`t,READING_DATETIME:chararray,CALENDER_KEY:int,EVENT_KEY:int,GENERAL_SUPPLY_KWH:float,CONTROLLED_LOAD_KWH:float,GROSS_GENERATION_KWH:float,NET_GENERATION_KWH:float,OTHER_KWH:float); 

test = FOREACH records GENERATE CUSTOMER_ID,READING_DATETIME;

dates= FOREACH test GENERATE  CUSTOMER_ID,ToDate(READING_DATETIME,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') AS READING_DATETIME;
```

Sample data from sample.csv is below, (first two columns only pasted here)

```
CUSTOMER_ID READING_DATETIME
10017574    31-05-2013 18:30
10017574    10-06-2013 05:30
10017574    29-06-2013 04:30
10017574    04-07-2013 20:30
10017574    05-07-2013 17:00
10017574    12-07-2013 10:30
10017574    13-07-2013 20:00
10017574    16-07-2013 13:00
10017574    19-07-2013 20:00
```

The above commands are executing properly. Also when I use DESCRIBE for 'dates',
it returns :

```
grunt> DESCRIBE dates
dates: {CUSTOMER_ID: int,READING_DATETIME: datetime}
```

Now when I use

```
toPrint = LIMIT dates 5;
DUMP toPrint;



  2016-09-15 05:43:39,000 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Some jobs have failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
    2016-09-15 05:43:39,013 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias toPrint. Backend error : Invalid format: "READING_DATETIME"
```

I have verified the string format several times. Even I checked from oracle simple data format which is used in JODA class for date times used by pig. 
I have tried several combinations for the same data. Tried  brwosing online. Still issue not resolved. Seems to be a very silly thing for me but cudn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

From the sample data you have attached, the data does not look like it is comma separated.In your load statement you are using ',' as the delimiter.
In order to fix this you have 2 options.

1. Convert the input file to a comma separated input file
   Or
2. Use the correct delimiter to load the data.

I have used tab as the delimiter and it works fine.See below

**Data**

```
10017574    31-05-2013 18:30
10017574    10-06-2013 05:30
10017574    29-06-2013 04:30
10017574    04-07-2013 20:30
10017574    05-07-2013 17:00
10017574    12-07-2013 10:30
10017574    13-07-2013 20:00
10017574    16-07-2013 13:00
10017574    19-07-2013 20:00
```

**Script**

```
records = LOAD 'test12.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (CUSTOMER_ID:int,READING_DATETIME:chararray); 
test = FOREACH records GENERATE CUSTOMER_ID,READING_DATETIME;
dates= FOREACH test GENERATE  CUSTOMER_ID,ToDate(READING_DATETIME,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') AS READING_DATETIME;
DUMP dates;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: the problem might not be with delimiter, I tried using '\t' and the file doesn't load at all. It returns file not read error in 'input' section of pig output.  The reason tab worked for you might be because I pasted CSV as text. Can you suggest me what to do ? Also, previously when I dumped ' records' stored with ',' , it worked well. I could see the output.